# Terminal right Side

Tags: visual-studio-code

I uninstalled VsCode and installed it again, because i had some issues.

Before i uninstalled it, my terminal was always at the bottom (right side). As soon as i open my terminal i had like two separate windows open, but the terminal was always on the right side at the bottom. I got used to it.

But now the terminal look like this.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H16ER.png)

It should look like two screens and then the terminal on the right side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the picture you have uploaded

[image]

You can see the word `TERMINAL`. Right click on it and choose the Panel Position to be wherever you want it. In this case right.

Edit:

After reading your comment, maybe this is what you mean?

For me I have my side bar on the right because that is how I like it. I was able to set my terminal to be on the bottom of the side bar like the following image:

[image]

I was able to do that by dragging the `TERMINAL` button in the first picture and dropping at the bottom of the side bar.

Is that what you needed?

Comment: yeah but i mean, bottom right...

Comment: Check my edited answer @Meak